# ValueError: Cannot get dimension 'nO' for model 'sparse_linear': value unset error

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When as I run my code Im getting the error 'ValueError: Cannot get dimension 'nO' for model 'sparse_linear': value unset'.

If anyone could help me, that'd be great.
Thanks

I've done a fair bit of hunting around, trying to fix the bug, in which most say the issue is due to a spacy library issue and I'm needing to update spacy which I have.
Here are my versions:
Name: spacy . Version: 3.6.1
Name: thinc . Version: 8.1.9

This is how they're added in my code:
import spacy
from spacy.training.example import Example

Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Ive tried updating, but Im still getting the same error.
If you need anymore code to help sort the issue, let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it using the below steps:

```
nlp=spacy.blank("en")
textcat = nlp.add_pipe('textcat_multilabel', last=True)
for label in df["category"].unique():
    textcat.add_label(label)
# Do the above before calling initialize.
optimizer=nlp.initialize()
```

As the Spacy documentation states:

> it is crucial that the output dimension of each component has already
> been defined either in the config, or by calling pipe.add_label for
> each possible output label (e.g. for the tagger or textcat).